# How to get list of pipelines' builds run on specific Jenkins agent?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I've came across an issue for which I need to identify all or certain number of builds(which could be running against one or more pipelines) for a specific Jenkins node.

I opened Jenkins node page and clicked on `Build History` but this page does not have any information.

Could you please help how can I get list of builds run on specific Jenkins node?